# Do users notice text changes on call to actions?

Tags: design-patterns, popup, indicator, cta

**Brief product Description**
So I have been working on a digital project where the product is an online presentation software where the user(Teacher) has presentation slides to select and
conducts presentations to the students.

**Problem**
The teacher needs to select a presentation slide before heading towards the lobby where the presentation takes place along with other students as you can see on the screens below. The usual process is that the user selects the desired presentation slide and clicks on "continue" and proceeds or the user selects "Continue without presentation slide" where the user gets the default presentation which is a welcome slide.However, the default slide can be changed in the account settings. When the user sets a default slide in the account settings and the slide is not available anymore. The user needs to know that. My initial thoughts were  to change the text on the call to action button from "Continue with Default Presentation"to "Continue without presentation slide(here the default slide would become the welcome slide)". But I am not sure if the user will notice this change or it is better to implement a tooltip like this https://codemyui.com/button-tooltip-hover/ but I think Defaults are used to make the process faster so I think this prolongs the users time. Hence, I think something like this would be more appropriate https://codemyui.com/wonky-rise-css-tooltip-hover/  What do you guyz think? Thank you

[image: when default slide is selected in the account settings]

[image: when default slide is not selected in the settings]

Answer (score 3):

I think you should avoid having two different continue buttons as this just adds confusion to the user as they need to work out which one they should click. This is made even more confusing if one of the continue buttons actually has different functionality depending on the text.

My suggestion would be to handle the default option by making it a selectable tile.

So the buttons will just be: **Back, Cancel, Continue**

Then add a new tile option that is the first option in the list. This should say something like "Use Default Slide" and will be the tile option that is automatically selected when the user first navigates on to this page.

This allows the user to then quickly click "continue" if they want the default, or they can select an alternate slide before clicking continue.

You can also use this panel to inform the user that the default is no longer available and make it so that tile is no longer selectable.

This improves the process because the user can immediately see what option is going to be used before they click to continue.

Everything makes more sense with pictures, so here you go...

**Default selected automatically**

[image]

---

**Default not available, another option selected**

[image]

---

**A step further**

I would also be tempted to take it a step further and show a preview of the default slide. This way the user will have no doubt what style is currently set as their preferred default.

[image]